# How to pass list of objects from angular component to html template created in material design

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I have method getReports in my angular component where I subscribe to endpoint which looks like list of objects after console log, and where I want to display form, until issi, status for every report that I have in my list. But seems that I didn't properly passed data from component to html, I also use material ui for design.

```
{
"content": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "from": "2022-03-14T23:00:00",
        "until": "2022-03-15T13:37:00",
        "issi": "1500",
        "format": "KML",
        "creationDate": "2023-01-19T11:53:40.018808",
        "status": "DOWNLOADABLE"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "from": "2022-03-14T23:00:00",
        "until": "2022-03-15T13:37:00",
        "issi": "1500",
        "format": "KML",
        "creationDate": "2023-01-19T11:54:23.810516",
        "status": "DOWNLOADABLE"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "from": "2022-03-14T23:00:00",
        "until": "2022-03-15T13:37:00",
        "issi": "1500",
        "format": "CSV",
        "creationDate": "2023-01-19T11:55:24.018175",
        "status": "DOWNLOADABLE"
    },
],
"pageable": {
    "sort": {
        "empty": false,
        "sorted": true,
        "unsorted": false
    },
    "offset": 0,
    "pageNumber": 0,
    "pageSize": 25,
    "unpaged": false,
    "paged": true
},
"totalPages": 1,
"totalElements": 12,
"last": true,
"size": 25,
"number": 0,
"sort": {
    "empty": false,
    "sorted": true,
    "unsorted": false
},
"first": true,
"numberOfElements": 12,
"empty": false}
```

here is my component

```
import {Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {MatPaginator} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {ReportInterface} from "../../types/ReportInterface";
import {MatTableDataSource} from "@angular/material/table";
import {ReportsService} from "../../services/reports.service";
import {saveAs} from "file-saver";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-reports-table',
  templateUrl: './reports-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./reports-table.component.scss']
})
export class ReportsTableComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  public displayedColumns: string[] = ['createdAt', 'from', 'until', 'devices', 'status', 'action'];
  @Input() data: ReportInterface[] = [];
  dataSource!: MatTableDataSource<any>;
  // @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  constructor(private reportsService: ReportsService) {

  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getReports();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    // this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }

  downloadReport(id: number, format: 'CSV' | 'KML') {
    this.reportsService.downloadReport(id).subscribe((buffer) => {
      const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], {
        type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8"
      });

      if (format === 'CSV') {
       return  saveAs(data, "report-" + id + ".csv");
      }

      return saveAs(data, "report-" + id + ".kml");
    });
  }

  getReports() {
    this.reportsService.getAllReports().subscribe({
      next: (element:ReportInterface[]) => {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(element);
        console.log('aco',element);
      },
      error: (err) => {
        alert('Error while fetching users');
      },
    });
  }
}
```

and also my HTML template

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="reports-table">


  <!-- Create at Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="createdAt">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Created at </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.creationDate | date: 'd/M/yy - H:mm'}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- From Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="from">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> From </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.from | date: 'd/M/yy - H:mm'}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Until Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="until">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> To </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.until | date: 'd/M/yy - H:mm'}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Status Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Status </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.status.toLowerCase()}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Devices Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="devices">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Devices </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.issi}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Actions Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Action </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <button mat-button class="download-button" (click)="downloadReport(element.id, element.format)">Download in {{element.format}}</button>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

  <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"
                 showFirstLastButtons
                 aria-label="Select page of periodic elements">
  </mat-paginator>
</table>
```